# How to enforce JBoss AS 7.0.1 SSL connector Protocol to use TLS 1.2 only

Tags: windows, ssl, jboss7.x

JBoss AS 7.0.1 SSL connector Protocol to use TLS 1.2 only and disable SSL v2, V3 and TLS v1, V1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set value for Protocol attribute as "TLSv1.2". 
But this wont work for JDK 1.6. We have to use JDK 1.7 or later.